# Surjection of the perfection of two characteristic $p$ rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am currently taking a short course on p-adic geometry, and coming up with the following exercise:

> **Exercise**: Let $f: A \rightarrow B$ be a ring homomorphism of rings of characteristic $p>0$. It induces a homomorphism
> $$
> f^{\mathrm{perf}}: A^{\mathrm{perf}} \rightarrow B^{\mathrm{perf}}.
> $$
> Then
>
> - $f^{\mathrm{perf}}$ is injective if and only if $\bigcap_{n} (\ker f)^{p^n} = 0$.
> - $f^{\mathrm{perf}}$ is surjective if and only if $\mathrm{im}(f)[\mathrm{perf}] = B[\mathrm{perf}]$, where for a ring $R$ of char $p>0$, $R[\mathrm{perf}]$ is the set of perfect elements in $R$, that is, elements with arbitrary $p$-power roots.

I can figure out the first conclusion by straightforward definitions. But I am getting stuck on the **if** direction of the surjectivity, i.e. the direction to show the surjectivity of $f^{\mathrm{perf}}$.

**My attempts**: Let $b=(b_0, \ldots) \in B^{\mathrm{perf}}$, then I am hoping to find an $a = (a_0, \ldots) \in A^{\mathrm{perf}}$ that maps to $b$.

As $b_0$ is a perfect element in $B$ (with arbitrary $p^{n}$-th power root $b_n$), by assumption $b_0$ lies in $\mathrm{im}(f)[\mathrm{perf}]$. Hence there exists $a_0, a_1, \ldots \in A$ such that $f(a_0) = b_0$ with $b_i^{\prime} = f(a_i)$ as a $p^n$-th power root of $b_0$. But then I got stuck on adjusting $a_i$ such that simultaneously

1. $(a_i) \in A^{\mathrm{perf}}$, and
2. $f(a_i) = b_i$.

Actually **for (1)**, since $(b_i^{\prime})^{p^i} = b_0$, we see that $f(a_i^{p^i}) = f(a_0)$. To show $a_i^{p^i} = a_0$, it seems that we need some injectivity condition on $f$?

So I doubt whether the conclusion in the exercise is correct or not. I have read the post  [Isomorphism of the perfection of two ring](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3204026/isomorphism-of-the-perfection-of-two-ring), where the proof of the surjectivity part **does rely on the nilpotency of $\ker f$**.

And **for (2)**, I am actually hoping to use the observation that not only $b_0 \in B[\mathrm{perf}]$, but every $b_i \in B[\mathrm{perf}]$ as well. So actually for each $i \geq 0$, we can do the same thing as above, and get
$$
b_0= f(a_0^{(0)}), b_1^{(0)} = f(a_1^{(0)}),  b_2^{(0)} = f(a_2^{(0)}), b_3^{(0)} = f(a_3^{(0)}), \ldots;
$$
$$
b_0, b_1 = f(a_1^{(1)}),  b_2^{(1)} = f(a_2^{(1)}), b_3^{(1)} = f(a_3^{(1)}), \ldots;
$$
$$
b_0, b_1 ,  b_2, b_3^{(2)} = f(a_3^{(2)}), \ldots; \vdots
$$
But it seems that this only complicates things, and I have no idea how to carry on.

So now I am getting stuck here. Thank you all for commenting and answering!

Comment: Indeed, one really needs the kernel to be nilpotent in the question that you link (though maybe some other finiteness hypothesis can yield Mittag-Leffler and thus the conclusion). How confident are you that the statement is correct as is?

Comment: How about a surjection from $\mathbb{F}_p[T]$ to a finite field (strictly greater than $\mathbb{F}_p$)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The criterion for surjectivity seems false as is. It implies in particular that $f^{perf}$ is onto whenever $f$ is.

But consider a surjection $f: A:=\mathbb{F}_p[T] \rightarrow F$, where $F \neq \mathbb{F}_p$ is a finite field. Then $A^{perf}=\mathbb{F}_p$, so that $f^{perf}$ cannot be surjective.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I see that indeed the criterion is false. I will ask the lecturer about this tomorrow. Thank you for your counterexample! I realize how unfamiliar I am with such concrete examples of perfections. :(

Comment: Before I saw your counterexample, actually I was considering correcting the conclusion as $f(A[\mathrm{perf}])=B[\mathrm{perf}]$. As your example shows, this is also daydreaming, since it seems that $A[\mathrm{perf}] = \mathbb{F}_p$ and its image via $f$ is a copy of $\mathbb{F}_p$, while $B[\mathrm{perf}] = F \neq \mathbb{F}_p$.